# How can I update attribute in Sequelize Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js, email-verification

I'm trying to validate a user email by decoding a JWT token given as parameter in a GET request.

In case the token is valid and the User is not verified yet, I want to update isVerified column to true.

Why is my Promise always rejected ?

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const request = require('request');
const models = require('../models');


/**
 * GET /verify-email/:token
 */
exports.verifyEmail = function(req, res) {
  jwt.verify(req.params.token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, function(err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      res.send({
        msg: 'Token is invalid or has expired'
      })
    }
    models.User.findOne({
      where: {
        email: decoded.email,
        id: decoded.id
      }
    }).then(record => {
      if (!record) {
        res.send({
          msg: 'User not found'
        })
      } else if (record.isVerified) {
        res.send({
          msg: 'User already verified'
        })
      } else {
        console.log('user mail ' + record.email + ' will be verified in db')
        record.update({
            isVerified: true,
          })
          .then(() => res.status(200).send({
            msg: 'User has been verified'
          }))
          .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I had a beforeValidation hook in my model :

```
if (!user.changed('password')) {
    return sequelize.Promise.reject("not modified");
}
```